# SQL request to list all databases in an instance of Sql-Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to list all of the existing databases in an instance of Sql Server via a SQL request ?

More generally can I use SQL to fully read the schema of the databases (tables, columns, ..) ?

Thank you

Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Sp_msforeachdb`, there is also a `sp_msforeachtable`. You can use both to iteratively retrieve all tables in all DB's and get what you want.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=395.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See the [Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) and [sys.databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx).

Here's a script for table definitions that may be useful. http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Script-Table-definitions-using-TSQL/0,339028455,339293405,00.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lot of infos by the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases

use Northwind

select * from sys.objects where type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'

SELECT t1.name [table], t2.* 
FROM sys.objects t1
        inner join sys.columns t2 on t1.object_id = t2.object_id 
where type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'

sp_help 'Customers' -- Customers = tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the stored procedure [sp_databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176070.aspx) to get the list of all db